# Strategy to handle shortcuts correctly with a BarManager

Tags: winforms, devexpress, shortcut, menubar

We are using the DevExpress BarManager to build our menus but I know that the problem described below occurs with other menu-handling components as well:

We have encountered a conceptual problem using the BarManager. We have a base form class from which all our forms are derived. This base form has a BarManager which, as a matter of fact, handles every shortcut that occurs, including shortcuts that normally would be handled by the currently focused control. This of course is not the desired behaviour. Consider this example:  If a text box is focussed, hitting CTRL + C will NOT cause the text box to copy its text-value to the clipboard. Instead, the BarManager will fire a BarItemClick-event.

Now we have evaluated several strategies to solve this problem in a generic way. We clearly have the requirement that our framework handles the problem entirely, and that individual programmers or applications do not have care about it. So a solution as it is suggested in the following example is not applicable, because it depends on an application-specific logic: [example](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5417).

We found out that there are basically two ways to solve the problem generically:

1. The BarManager always handles the shortcut in a BarItemClick event handler. If a control is focussed, the control is told to take care of the shortcut if possible. If the control could not take care of the shortcut (e.g. because the shortcut is CTRL + S), the BarManager passes the event to the application (e.g. save the current document on CTRL + S).
2. The BarManager has a ShortcutItemClick event which is fired whenever a shortcut occurs. In a respective event handler, the focussed control is asked whether it can handle this shortcut. If yes (e.g. CTRL + C), the BarManager will cancel handling the shortcut and the control will react on the shortcut as if there were no BarManager at all (e.g. copy the controls content to the clipboard). If no (e.g. CTRL + S), the BarManager will handle the shortcut, which means it fires its BarItemClick event, which will lead to the application taking care of it (e.g. save the current document).

Now for each solution we have several ideas how an implementation could look like, but they all are not working a satisfying way:

**For solution 1:**

A)  Call BaseEdit.SendKey() on the focussed control. This would be the most self-contained solution because there is no logic to be implemented. The problem is: Calling BaseEdit.SendKey() and passing the key of the shortcut has no effect. For example SendKey(new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Delete)) does NOT delete the selection of the focussed text box. 
My question is: Why does this method call have no effect?

B)  Define a interface IShortcutHandler which has one method HandleShortcut(). All used controls implement the interface in the following way:

```
public void HandleShortcut(KeyEventArgs args)
{
  base.OnKeyDown(args);
}
```

This solution also has the problem that calling OnKeyDown has no effect, just as in A). 
My question is: Why is this?

**For solution 2:**

A)  Call a method on the control that determines whether the control is able to handle the shortcut. My question is: Is there such a method or a helper class or a library or anything that can take the decision?

Are there any other strategies or solutions that you can think of?